# Can't find Method in handler

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to create a basic UI with JavaFX. The problem is only that my Handlers can't be found in my controller.

my ui.fxml:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<StackPane id="pane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="reldb0.controller.PersonOverviewController">
    <children>
        <Button text="Hinzufügen" onAction="#handleAddClicked" fx:id="addButton" />
        <Button text="Entfernen" onAction="#handleDeleteClicked" fx:id="deleteButton" />
        <TableView fx:id="table">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="vorname" prefWidth="100" text="Vorname" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="nachname" prefWidth="100" text="Nachname" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </children>
 </StackPane>
```

My Controller class:

```
package reldb0.controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import reldb0.entity.Person;
import reldb0.MockData;

/**
 *
 * @author hnsdi
 */
public class PersonOverviewController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> vorname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> nachname;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        vorname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("vorname"));
        nachname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("nachname"));    

        table.getItems().setAll(MockData.persons());
    }  

    @FXML
    private void handleAddClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

        Stage addWindow = new Stage();
        addWindow.setTitle("Person hinzufügen");
        addWindow.setScene(scene);

        addWindow.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDeleteClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

I can't find the issue why my EventHandlers can't be found. I have the @FXML Annotations and the controller is registered correctly because the Table is filled with the data.

Comment: Do you tried to rebuild the complete project?

Comment: No, I have not tried that. When I remove the ActionEvent from my signature it works. But then I can not access the event in my handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; // which is wrong
```

Import `javafx.event.ActionEvent` instead of `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` in your `PersonOverviewController` class